# How can I replace a number of DIVs with a single element in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have some DIVs that appear on the bottom of each of my pages:

```
<div id="message" ng-show="test.stateService.displayMessage">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                {{ test.stateService.message }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can use Angular to simplify this code so that I do not need to add the same code block to every page?

Comment: Why so many useless divs? But CaspNZs directive should be the right way.

Comment: Yeah, I was going on the assumption that there is other stuff in the divs and Samantha has simplified it - am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use a directive like so:

```
app.directive('codeblock', function() {
    return {
    scope: true,  // use a child scope that inherits from parent
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '<div>\
                 <div>\
                   <div>\
                     {{ test.stateService.message }}\
                   </div>\
                 </div>\
               </div>'
    };
});
```

You'd call it like this:

```
<div codeblock id="message" ng-show="test.stateService.displayMessage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

You can save this div as a file, say `footer.htm` and add the below code to the bottom of all pages.

```
<div ng-include="footer.htm"></div>
```

But this code also needs to be given at the bottom of all pages. So I am not sure how it can save your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get rid of adding at least some code on each of the pages. Using an html template with `ng-include` would be one of the approaches.